# Python and MySQL connection problems (mysqldb api)

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection, mysql-python

I have config.ini:

```
[mysql]
host=localhost
port=3306
user=root
passwd=abcdefgh
db=testdb
unix_socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I have this class:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb,ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

class MySQL( object ):

    def __init__( self ):
        self.host   = config.get("mysql","host")
        self.port   = config.get("mysql","port")
        self.user   = config.get("mysql","user")
        self.passwd = config.get("mysql","passwd")
        self.db     = config.get("mysql","db")
        self.unix_socket = config.get("mysql","unix_socket")

        self.conn   = MySQLdb.Connect(self.host,
                                      self.port,
                                      self.user,
                                      self.passwd,
                                      self.db,
                                      self.unix_socket)

        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor ( MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor )

    def __del__( self ):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.conn.close()
```

and this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
from mysql import MySQL

class Incident( MySQL ):

    def getIncidents( self ):
        self.cursor.execute("""*VALID QUERY*""")
        return self.cursor.fetchall()
```

and finally this:

```
import subprocess, os, alarm
from Queue import Queue
from incident_model import Incident

fileQueue = Queue()

def enumerateFilesPath():
  global fileQueue
  incident = Incident()
  incidents = incident.getIncidents()
  for i in incidents:
    fileQueue.put("MD5")

def main():
    global fileQueue
    enumerateFilesPath()
```

Output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "./mwmonitor.py", line 202, in
>   
>       main()   File "./mwmonitor.py", line 184, in main
>       enumerateFilesPath()         File "./mwmonitor.py", line 86, in
>   enumerateFilesPath
>       incident = Incident()       File "/usr/share/mwanalysis/core/mysql.py",
>   line 23, in **init**
>       self.unix_socket)       File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/**init**.py",
>   line 81, in Connect
>       return Connection(*args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/connections.py",
>   line 170, in **init**
>       super(Connection, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs2)
>   TypeError: an integer is required
>   Exception AttributeError: "'Incident'
>   object has no attribute 'cursor'" in
>   
>   
>   0xa03d46c>> ignored

If someone can help detect and correct the error would greatly appreciate.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So... did you want to connect via TCP/IP or via Unix domain sockets?

Comment: Good catch, both are not needed.  But if connection failed, wouldn't __init__() raise exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `__del__` method is causing confusion. Specifically, it refers to `self.cursor` and `self.conn` which may never get created if, for example, `MySQLdb.Connect` raises an exception (which is what seems to happen).

I suggest you modify your class as follows:

```
class MySQL( object ):

    def __init__( self ):

        self.conn   = None
        self.cursor = None

        self.host   = config.get("mysql","host")
        self.port   = config.get("mysql","port")
        self.user   = config.get("mysql","user")
        self.passwd = config.get("mysql","passwd")
        self.db     = config.get("mysql","db")
        self.unix_socket = config.get("mysql","unix_socket")

        self.conn   = MySQLdb.Connect(self.host,
                                      self.port,
                                      self.user,
                                      self.passwd,
                                      self.db,
                                      self.unix_socket)

        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor ( MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor )

    def __del__( self ):
        if self.cursor is not None:
            self.cursor.close()
        if self.conn is not None:
            self.conn.close()
```

This won't solve the problem, but should give better diagnostic.

Now to the actual problem that you're experiencing. I strongly suspect that you're supplying the arguments to `Connect` in the wrong order, or the types aren't quite right, or something along those lines. To quote the docstring for `Connection.__init__`:

```
    Create a connection to the database. It is strongly recommended
    that you only use keyword parameters. Consult the MySQL C API
    documentation for more information.

    host
      string, host to connect

    user
      string, user to connect as

    passwd
      string, password to use

    db
      string, database to use

    port
      integer, TCP/IP port to connect to

    unix_socket
      string, location of unix_socket to use

    ...
```

**"It is strongly that you only use keyword parameters."** I recommend that you do just that when you call `MySQLdb.Connect`. Also, make sure that `port` is an `int` and not a string.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's expecting `port` to be an integer rather than a string. Try:

```
self.port   = int(config.get("mysql","port"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a connectivity error. Have you checked the type of the incident_model ?
`TypeError: an integer is required
Exception AttributeError: "'Incident'object has no attribute 'cursor'" in`